# perl split multiple commas in line

Tags: perl

I am trying to split these values with colon separated

my input:

```
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" request_id=bbfd6a1f-90c4-45g52-9e7c-db5 message="Authentication success"
```

I am using this code block

```
while ( my $line = <IN> ) {
    chomp $line;
    print "$line\n";
    my @values = split( /\s+/, $line );

    foreach $data (@values) {
        chomp $data;
        ( $key, $value ) = split( /=/, $data );
        $key =~ s/\s+//g;
        $key =~ s/"//g;
    }
}
```

I am receiving this output, it take the space between the values, how to split the keys and values exactly from the above input

```
_1;
Linux
x86_64;
rv:23.0)
Gecko/20100101es,OU
(X1
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution makes use of the `(?|)` matching groups introduced in perl 5.10 (I think). If you don't want to save into a hash, you can extend the line with the `while` loop. inside the `while`, the key is in `$1` and the value is in `$2`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.01;

while (<DATA>){
  chomp;
  my %header;
  $header{$1} = $2 while (/\G\s*(\S+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S*))/g); #extend here
  printf "%9s => %s\n", $_, $header{$_} for keys %header;
}


__DATA__
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" request_id=bbfd6a1f-90c4-45g52-9e7c-db5 message="Authentication success"
```

This prints:

```
message    => Authentication success
user_agent => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
request_id => bbfd6a1f-90c4-45g52-9e7c-db5
```

If the quoting gets more complex, you should look at `Text::Balanced` with it's `extract_quotelike` routine.

Comment: @scm: it is customary around here to accept an answer to let people know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `"` would not appear as valid value character,

```
my %hash;
while (my $line = <IN>)
{
  $hash{$1} = ($2 // $3) while $line =~ /(\w+)=(?: "(.+?)" | (\S+) )/xg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll try this method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [perlretut - Alternative capture group numbering](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Alternative-capture-group-numbering) to capture values as either quote enclosed or non-spaces.

Then because the capture groups are arranged in key value pairs, it's possible to directly initialize your hash like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my %hash = /\G([^=]+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S*))\s*/g;

    use Data::Dump;
    dd \%hash;
}

__DATA__
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" request_id=bbfd6a1f-90c4-45g52-9e7c-db5 message="Authentication success"
```

Outputs:

```
{
  message    => "Authentication success",
  request_id => "bbfd6a1f-90c4-45g52-9e7c-db5",
  user_agent => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0",
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/USx4O0)</kbd>